# Easiest way to distribute an application to be download and updated via SVN?

Tags: svn, installation, svn-checkout

I have a client that must install a web application by himself, is there a way I can send him a package(installer) that installs TortoiseSVN and checkout a working copy of the code?

I Guess I can always make an NSIS installer, but maybe, just maybe there is already an application that do that.

Thanks!

Comment: Of course i prefer that to be done via SVN, so I can fix and extend the code in my house and he can just update his working copy

Comment: Because I want this question to not generate reputation and be editable by users with more than 100rep.

Comment: Well sure, you could just tell your client to download TortoiseSVN and tell him the URL of your repository.  (Presumably with permissions to prevent the client from doing commits.)  But using SVN sounds like a fair amount of overkill (plus you get into the problem of the client's web server containing copies of the .svn folders, etc.)